# Issue while using Preceding axis in XPath and XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am learning XSLT 2.0 and XPath. While creating the examples I came across to preceding axis available in XPath and created the below example.

Please find the below order.xml file used as input.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <Order id="12345">
    <Item>
        <ItemId>007</ItemId>
        <ItemName>iPhone 5</ItemName>
        <Price>500</Price>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ItemId>456</ItemId>
        <ItemName>Ipad</ItemName>
        <Price>600</Price>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ItemId>7864567</ItemId>
        <ItemName>Personal Development Book</ItemName>  
        <Price>10</Price>
        <Quantity>10</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ItemId>123</ItemId>
        <ItemName>Java Book</ItemName>
        <Price>20</Price>
        <Quantity>12</Quantity>
    </Item>
</Order>
```

Please find the below XSLT testaxis.xsl file used for transformation of the above XML.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select="count(/Order/Item[ItemName='Ipad']/ItemName/preceding::*)" />
</xsl:template>
```

The output after transformation is 
**6**

Here context node is below one if I am not wrong.

```
<ItemName>Ipad</ItemName>
```

If we count all the nodes which are before the context node then counts come to **5** .
Now coming to the question, why it is showing the count of the nodes as **6** in the output?

Please do let me know if I misunderstood anything

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about which node is the context node, and that node *does* have 6 preceding elements:

- The first `<Item>` element.
- The four elements inside that.
- The `<ItemId>` element immediately before the context node.

That makes six. You can verify this by doing the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text" />
 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select="/Order/Item[ItemName='Ipad']/ItemName/preceding::*">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), '&#xA;')" />
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: But as per the description given in W3C for Preceding axis states below "the preceding-sibling axis contains all the preceding siblings of the context node; if the context node is an attribute node or namespace node, the preceding-sibling axis is empty". Here the Item node we are talking about is not the sibling

Comment: That's the definition for the `preceding-sibling` axis, but you are using the `preceding` axis.  The context node here only has one preceding sibling.

Comment: Thanks JLRishe for your quick reply. Have one doubt as per the Preceding axis description in the W3C "the preceding axis contains all nodes in the same document as the context node that are before the context node in document order, excluding any ancestors and excluding attribute nodes and namespace nodes" as per the description ancestor nodes need to be excluded.In my example <Item> node is the ancestor node of the ItemName. am I right? If I am then why it is been counted?

Comment: The first `Item` element in the document is not an ancestor of the context node. That is why it is being counted.

Comment: Thanks JLRishe for your quick reply. But If I add id attribute to the first Item element then it would become the attribute node.Is it? If it is then it must not get counted as per the preceding axis defination?

Comment: If you added an id attribute to it, then it would _have_ an attribute node. It would not _become_ an attribute node.

Answer (score 1):

The preceding elements are the ones marked below with a "*"

```
<*Item>
    <*ItemId>007</ItemId>
    <*ItemName>iPhone 5</ItemName>
    <*Price>500</Price>
    <*Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Item>
<Item>
    <*ItemId>456</ItemId>
```

You will see that there are six of them.